# Scala permutations via flatMap of subset

Tags: algorithm, scala

I have the method which makes permutations:

```
def permutations[T](lst: List[T]): List[List[T]] = lst match {
    case Nil => List(Nil)
    case x :: xs => permutations(xs) flatMap { perm =>
      (0 to xs.length) map { num =>
        (perm take num) ++ List(x) ++ (perm drop num)
      }
    }
  }
```

Firstly, it take a recursive call with pair - head, tail for List("a","b", "c"):
c - Nil
b - c
a - bc

and permute before and after parts. As result, I have all permutations from three later. My question is next: why recursive call doesn't return the intermediate statement like "bc", "cb", "c" and return valid set from three later.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to implement your own, but in case you didn't know `Seq` has a `permutations` method (`List` implements `Seq`).

Comment: I know about permutation method in Seq, it's just an experiment with combinatorics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in each iteration you necessarily return only lists with the same size as the input list, because you return permutations of the form `(perm take num) ++ List(x) ++ (perm drop num)`, which would always contain all of the elements in `perm` plus the `x` element.

Therefore, recursively - if each cycle returns only values of the same size as its input (including the end case of `Nil`), then the end result must only contain permutations of the same size.

To fix this, you can add the `perm` **without** `x` to each cycle's result, but you'll have to add `distinct` to get rid of duplications:

```
def permutations[T](lst: List[T]): List[List[T]] = lst match {
  case Nil => List(Nil)
  case x :: xs => permutations(xs) flatMap { perm =>
    ((0 to xs.length) flatMap { num =>
      List(perm, (perm take num) ++ List(x) ++ (perm drop num))
    }).distinct
  }
}
```

Comment: You said that "in each iteration you necessarily return only lists with the same size as the input list", what about case where `perm` contains only single element (e.g. "c") in a recursive call, it must return `List(x)+"c"`, and length won't coincide to input list length

Comment: but `perm` _can't_ contain only single element `c` because this claim is true for the recursive call creating `perm`! Think of the laws of "proof by induction": if you prove the "basis" claim (for `Nil`, all results have size 0), and the "inductive step" (if we _assume_ `perm.size == xs.size` then the results of the iteration all have the same size as `lst` - which is what I showed), then - the claim stands for ALL iterations.

Comment: I don't think that `perm` contains a strict count of elements as `lst` on each iteration, I append println to out `perm` and it was `Nil` `"c"`,`"bc"`, `"cb"`.

Comment: It gives different sizes only in _different iterations_ - within the same iteration, all values of `perm` have the same size.

Comment: yes, it's true, you said: "each cycle returns only values of the same size as its input", does it appropriate for any recursive call?

Comment: Only for the method as you implemented it - obviously not for _any_ method, e.g. my corrected version...

Comment: what is a cause so my method do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131598/discussion-between-tzach-zohar-and-pacman).